# innerHTML pass in variable to function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which is pulling data from firebase:

```
r.insertCell(23).innerHTML = doc.data().username;
r.insertCell(24).innerHTML = doc.data().uid;
r.insertCell(25).innerHTML ='<button onclick="activateUserInTable('+doc.data().uid +')">Activate User</button>';
```

I have a function:

```
function activateUserInTable(userId) {
  db.collection("users").doc(userId).update({
  activated: 1,
 });
}
```

I have a button in my table:

```
r.insertCell(25).innerHTML ='<button onclick="activateUserInTable('+doc.data().uid +')">Activate User</button>';
```

Im trying to pass `doc.data().uid` into the button above in the table.

But this doesn't seem to work. This function does work if its outside the table and i manually pass in a `uid`. I want to be able to pass in the data from firebase into the function while the button is in the table.

Comment: What does the actual HTML string this creates look like? Are you IDs actually numbers?

Comment: mixture of numbers and characters

Comment: Well then the parameter value is of course missing string delimiters.

Comment: @GurmukhSingh - FYI, I've updated my answer to fix a potential issue with the value of `doc.data().uid` changing between when the button is created and when it's clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to avoid setting event handlers via text assigned to `onxyz` attributes. It has several issues, not least that you have to create the text correctly (quotes are easily confused or mismatched), the browser has to parse it as code, and any functions you use have to be globals.

Instead, just use a function you create right then and there and attach it via [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
r.insertCell(23).innerHTML = doc.data().username;
r.insertCell(24).innerHTML = doc.data().uid;
const button = document.createElement("button");
button.type = "button";
button.addEventListener(
    "click",
    activateUserInTable.bind(null, doc.data().uid)
);
button.textContent = "Activate User";
r.insertCell(25).appendChild(button);
```

(I've used `bind` there so we're capturing the value of `doc.data().uid` as of when we create the function, not later when the function is called.)

That said, I think I'd avoid repeatedly calling `doc.data()`. Also, I'd avoid the XSS vulnerability that treating `username` as HTML might provide (and the same for `uid`, though I'm guessing it's a less likely vector) by treating them purely as text via `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`. Something like this:

```
const { username, uid } = doc.data();
r.insertCell(23).textContent = username;
r.insertCell(24).textContent = uid;
const button = document.createElement("button");
button.type = "button"; // I added this, it wasn't in your HTML, but note that
                        // the default `type` of `button` elements is
                        // `"submit"`. Only matters if this is in a `form`...
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    activateUserInTable(uid);
});
button.textContent = "Activate User";
r.insertCell(25).appendChild(button);
```

(I don't need `bind` there and can use the easier to read [IMHO] arrow function because we've already captured the value of `doc.data().uid` to the `uid` constant.)